Notification sound when device silent or vibrate
My project want to make a chat feature with urgent message.
Has anyone here ever made to keep notification sound when device in silent or vibrate mode ?
How to do it ? im using FCM as notification service.
Already set the importance and priority to high.
i put this code at FirebaseMessagingService
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_doctor_apps)
        .setContentTitle(fixedTitle)
        .setContentText(fixedMessageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)

    notificationManager.notify(666 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())

and I put code file at my app
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "Channel human readable title",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        ).apply {
            description = "Description of this channel"
            setSound(
                Uri.parse(defaultSoundUri.toString()), AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .build())
        }

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }


On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Why are you trying to make a sound when a user has explicitly set their device to no sound / vibrate? What makes your use case special?

@dominicoder i've been edit the description.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

@DougStevenson I've been edit my question.

You have to use MediaPlayer as the notification sound.
Start a Service that play's the MediaPlayer when the notification is shown.
To Stop the sound, stop the service in the BroadCastReceiver of the notification's PendingIntent.
Don't forget to stop the sound when the notification cancels.
BUT This does not give you good feedback from users. Imagine you put your mobile in silent mode and you hear a notification, the first thing you do is delete the app that caused the sound.
